# Why aren't all my tweets posting?

Tags: android, twitter

I am using Twitter 4J to develop an Android app.  My app can post tweets but it can not  do it in quick succession (even if  the tweets all have different text).

Is there a time limit of how many tweets I can post close together?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API has changed a lot of stuff in there new startegy to demotivate 3rd party apps & bots.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting & http://support.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364